# Bar chart with longer names

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I have an quite simple bar chart. http://jsfiddle.net/6m2t6/3/ The problem is that I should have quite long names of LPU in my app and they overlap each other as you can see in fiddle.

```
data = '[{"lpu":"Some very Long Name (VERY VERY LONG) #1","amount":"1"},{"lpu":"Some very Long Name (VERY VERY LONG) #2","amount":"0"},{"lpu":"Some very Long Name (VERY VERY LONG) #3","amount":"0"},{"lpu":"Some very Long Name (VERY VERY LONG)","amount":"1"}]';
```

What is the best way to prevent it from overlaping and to have possibility to view full name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rotate the labels on the x axis.

This is a great blog post on that: http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/how-to-rotate-text-labels-for-x-axis-of.html

Also remember to put more space on the bottom of the chart to leave room for your labels

Hope this helps.