# Bar chart with longer name in two strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've previously created a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444648/bar-chart-with-longer-names). Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6m2t6/11/) of what I've done.
For some reason in fiddle it cuts the text value. In my app it is like this:
[image] It's not great too, because Names are too long. Can I make text value of xAxis to be in two strings somehow. I tried to do it like this:

```
var xLPUAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xLPU)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickSize(30,40);
```

But I get strange [result](http://jsfiddle.net/6m2t6/12/). Sollutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use a css text limit technique, like `text-overflow`? That will keep you xAxis on the desired size, adding a (...) to the end if overflows.

```
.limit {
    width: 100px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/95TuM/

Comment: Ok, it's fine, but how can I view the whole text in that case?

Comment: If you want to show it in two lines, remove the `overflow`, `text-overflow` and `white-space` properties, but keep the `width` size limiting the text... See updated: http://jsfiddle.net/95TuM/1/

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the following jQuery plugin: Trunk8
http://jrvis.com/trunk8/

You'll set a fixed width to the label container and you'll add the following code:

```
$('.label').trunk8({
    lines: 1,
    fill: '&hellip;'
});
```